# Cannot change root view's size or position from RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-view, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView on my android project. Today I had to change RecyclerView's right margin(or height & width or position... anything) when adapter's onBindViewHolder is called.

However I just ran into the problem the RecyclerView(or any views outside RecyclerView)'s size or position or margin... is not changed from adapter's onBindViewHolder(or any methods in adapter) method.

I tried with many ways but I gained no lucks. Can anybody tell what am I missing? :(

This is my code.

#### CODE

```
public class DataDashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView rvDashboard = null;
    private DataDashboardAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_dashboard, container, false);
        
        rvDashboard = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_dashboard);
        adapter = new DataDashboardAdapter();
        rvDashboard.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Here I add items which extracted from SQLite DAO.
        List<DailyDataUsage> items = SomeDAO.getItems();

        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(items);
        adapter.NDSC();

        return v;
    }

    ...

    // Adapter
    public class DataDashboardAdapter extends Adapter<DataDashboardViewHolder> {
        private List<DailyDataUsage> items = new ArrayList<DailyDataUsage>();

        ...

        public void clear() {
            this.items.clear();
        }

        public void NDSC() {
            // Some edits of data before notifyDataSetChanged.
            ...
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addAll(Collection<? extends DailyDataUsage> items) {
            this.items.addAll(items);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DataDashboardViewHolder holder, int position) {

            // rvDashboard's right margin won't be changed :(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rvDashboard.getLayoutParams();
            int rightMargin = 500;
            params.setMargins(0, 0, rightMargin, 0);
            rvDashboard.setLayoutParams(params);
            rvDashboard.requestLayout();

        }
    }

    // ViewHolder
    public static class DataDashboardViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

}
```

Any advice or similar experience would be thankful!

P.S. It works from fragment's onCreateView method(maybe some methods before create views) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can change in onCreateView method in onBindViewHolder method you can set margin to the holder elements or to the total layout of adapter and not to the RecyclerView . Actually why do you Need to set margin to RecyclerView at onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Because each item views' height in RecyclerView are all different. I had to calculate and affect each item views' height in onBindViewHolder method. It works well. But after that I want to adjust RecyclerView itself's margin or size or position for some purpose. So there's no way to do it. (The thing what I want to know is not alternative way. Exactly which reason make this situation :/)